# Trigger on child to update parent's field causes a process to fail

Tags: trigger, soql, lookup, after-trigger, child-to-parent

The certification object is the child and contact is the parent. They do not have a master-detail lookup relationship.

The code seems to run here and there, but I get this error, i checked everywhere for the 101 query part and limited the code to not execute 101 times.

> We can't save this record because the “Certificationv15.5”
> process failed. Give your Salesforce admin these details. This error
> occurred when the flow tried to update records:
> CANNOT_INSERT_UPDATE_ACTIVATE_ENTITY: ContactCertifications:
> System.LimitException: pw_ccpro:Too many SOQL queries: 101. You can
> look up ExceptionCode values in the SOAP API Developer Guide. Error
> ID: 1151868133-68659 (2103769226)

Even though this error says the issue is with ContactCertifications, it only occurs on when i activate another trigger which is named AccountCertifications, which is invoked by the ContactCertifications trigger. which is given secondly,
The process Certificationv15.5 never had issues and been in deployment for more than 3 years. I think the newly created triggers are faulty.

this trigger counts total passed certification as contact has..

```
trigger ContactCertifications on Certification__c (after update) {
    
    set<id> contactId = new set<id>();
    
    for(Certification__c c : Trigger.new){
        contactId.add(c.Contact__c);
    }
    
    Contact contact = [
        SELECT Id, Total_Certifications__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Id IN :contactId];
    
    List<Certification__c> certifications = new List<Certification__c>();
    certifications = [
        SELECT Id, Contact__r.Id, Certification_Awarded__c
        FROM Certification__c
        WHERE Certification_Awarded__c = TRUE AND Contact__r.Id IN :contactId];
    
    if(contactId.size() == 1){
        contact.Total_Certifications__c = certifications.size();
    }
    update contact;
}
```

---

The below trigger counts the total certification all of its contacts have.

```
trigger AccountCertifications on Contact (after update) {
    
    set<id> accountId = new set<id>();
    Integer zero = 0;
    
    for(Contact contact : Trigger.new){
        accountId.add(contact.AccountId);
    }
    
    Account account = [
        SELECT Id, Total_Contact_Certifications__c, Total_Certified_Contacts__c
        FROM Account
        WHERE Id IN :accountId];
    
    List<Contact> certifiedContacts = new List<Contact>();
    certifiedContacts = [
        SELECT Id, Total_Certifications__c, Account.Id, Account.Total_Contact_Certifications__c, Account.Total_Certified_Contacts__c
        FROM Contact
        WHERE Account.Id IN :accountId AND Total_Certifications__c > 0];
    
    Account.Total_Contact_Certifications__c = zero;
    Account.Total_Certified_Contacts__c = zero;
    
    for(Contact con : certifiedContacts){
        Account.Total_Contact_Certifications__c = Account.Total_Contact_Certifications__c + con.Total_Certifications__c;
        Account.Total_Certified_Contacts__c = Account.Total_Certified_Contacts__c + 1;
    }
    update account;
}
```

Comment: The SOQL query limit is cumulative through the entire transaction. The error you get just tells you the class that happened to push you over that limit. The triggers you've provided don't have any queries in loops, so figuring this out means you'll have to spend a good amount of time digging through a debug log. The "Analysis" perspective of a debug log (available through the developer console) may help.

Comment: I tried checking, but it was kinda hard to understand, I will try again as you have said. Thanks loads

Comment: @DerekF This seems to work, if i turn off some other trigger, any trigger to be exact. I think as you said, the collective of all trigger SOQL running during the update of the Contact and Account objects is above 101 apparently. I'm totally lost on what to do, does this mean, I will have to rewrite bad code(resource consuming code) in other triggers for this set of triggers to work? Can Process builder processes also affect this? Cause when a certain value is changed, the trigger and processes get triggered, or should I only worry about apex triggers/classes with SOQL queries?